# activating an disabling links if certain condition is met using php

Tags: php, css

I am creating a page where users pass info in a form that is saved in a session array and used on the next page that asks the user to upload images.
In the array there is a variable whose value is used to create a folder for that user. Once the folder is created the user must add at least 6 images and not more than 12 images to the folder before clicking the validate link that will redirect the user to the index page.

I want to create some functionality that will disable the validate link unless the above conditions are met.

Given that the name of the folder is that of `$_SESSION['data']['folder']`,
I can use the `glob` function to get the list of images in the folder then verify the conditions - but I'm not sure of how to disable the link if the condition is not met so the user should not validate an empty folder or a folder with less than 6 images.

below is the code i use to upload the images and display them on the page and also give the user the posibility to delete and add different images

```
<form id="file_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["test_file_upload.php"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="form_divs">
select a file:choice
<input type="file" name="image" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer " name="submit"/>
</div>
</form> 

<div class="form_divs">

<?php   
$images =  glob($_SESSION['data']['folder']."*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg,JPG,PNG,GIF,JPEG}",GLOB_BRACE);
    $get_img_number = sizeof($images);
    if($get_img_number < 6){
        echo '<p> you need atleast six images for this property</p>';
        echo '<a class="action_links" href="validate_property_upload" title="click here to  validate ">Validate</a>';   
    }else {
    echo '<a class="action_links" href="validate_property_upload" title="click here to  validate">Validate</a>';            
    }   
?>

<a class="action_links" href="stop_property_upload.php" title="click here to abort this operation">stop</a>
</div>

<div id='display images in folder'>
<?php
    $images =  glob($_SESSION['data']['folder']."*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg,JPG,PNG,GIF,JPEG}",GLOB_BRACE);
    $get_img_number = sizeof($images);
    if($get_img_number == 0){
        echo "<p class='none_img'>pas d'image pour le moment, merci d'ajouter des images pour ce bien</p>";
    }else{
    $get_img_number = ($get_img_number - 1);
    for($img = 0; $img <= $get_img_number; $img++){
    echo '<img class="house_img"src="'.$images[$img].'" title="house_image"/>';
    echo '<a href="delete_house_image.php?value='.$images[$img].'" title="delete this image from list ">Delete</a>';
    }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain the code with some sort of code or example

Comment: Why not just have 12 file input fields in the form and set 6 of them to be required?

Comment: Are you checking to make sure there's nothing malicious the user can enter as their folder name that would harm your server when you use their user submitted info to create the folder?

Why do you need to create actual folders on disk for each user?

I would just generate new unique file names for each image and save that name along with the ID of the user in a database. Then it is very easy to select all files that belong to only that user instead of relying on actual folders on the hard drive.

Comment: OmerMuhammad i have added the code i have and edited the question ,i am not checking to make sure the user files are malicious or not the file that does that is the test_file_upload.php to which the form is submitted and then redirect to this page on this page i want the user to see the images he/she has uploaded and an then validate so that the rest of the info saved in the session array can then move to the database the problem is i don't know what function to use to disable the validate link if the conditions are not met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found a solution it was not that complicated just needed to think abit 
i just added some php code around the validate button that printed an empty link button if the condition was not met the code is as below

```
<?php
$images =  glob($car_entry_data['folder']."*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg,JPG,PNG,GIF,JPEG}",GLOB_BRACE);
$get_img_number = sizeof($images);
if($get_img_number < 6){
    echo'<a class="wrong_link" href="#" title="ajoute au moin 6 images pour valider">Valider</a>';
}else{
    echo'<a class="action_links" href="validate_car_upload" title="cliquez ici pour valider l\'ajout de cette voiture">Valider</a>';
}
 ?>
```